# How to validate a REST request when a request's property is different to entity type

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-rest

I have an `@Valid` annotation to validate requests

```
public ResponseEntity<User> register(@Valid @RequestBody User user) {}
```

My User entity has password `Byte[]` because `user.password` is hashed before being stored. The request will need to have a password property as `String`, how can I validate the request with the `@Valid` annotation when there is a mismatch between storage type and the incoming request?

Answer (score 1):

You could write your own custom validator and use it over the User class's password field. `@Valid` annotation used in the controller method will then ensure to run your custom validation just after it gets the value. You would see numerous examples when you google for `custom validation spring`. Quoting some of them here:

1. http://dolszewski.com/spring/custom-validation-annotation-in-spring/
2. http://therealdanvega.com/blog/2017/05/01/add-validation-spring-entities
3. http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-validator